# Hide menu from user in openerp

Tags: odoo

I want to hide only settings menu from users. User must have all access and rights like admin.
i have tried it by creating group and overriding the settings menu. This is hiding settings menu from user but user doesn't get managerial rights of all modules. User should get managerial rights after any new modules is installed
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this, no need to create group or override it,

Login from the admin and Create a new User:-

- **Settings -> Users -> Users -> Create**
- See Second Notebook page name as **Access Rights**
- If you want to see menu **Setting** than select **Administration** as **Settings** option and if you want to hide menu from the User than leave it empty.

Hopes this will help you.

Comment: Hi Odedra, I have tried it. Setting menu is hiding but in this case user is unable to see all other menu like sales, purchase, accounting etc. If we installed any new module by default user must see all menus of that module. Thanks for reply

Comment: @Vishnu, than you need to give rights of that menu like manager, user or else option has.

Comment: Manually we can give manager rights to user from settings but it should take it automatically. At each time new module installed i shouldn't need to go to setting and give rights to user. For example i installed purchase module then user should automatically take it's managerial rights.